# Ayuda - Seleccionar un rango de años y se actualice automaticamente

Tags: javascript, html5, php7

Buenas tardes estoy teniendo un inconveniente en como plantear una solucion a una funcion que quiero agregar a mi pagina web,

Tengo un formulario para agregar nuevos registros en la cual tiene sus campos correspondientes y  me gustaria poder agregarle a un campo Año que aparezca el año actual Ej: 2020 y me despliegue 6 años menores a ese año es decir:

> 2020
>   -2019
>   -2018...etc

en mi pagina web utilizo html con javascript y php.

Soy bastante nuevo en el mundo del desarrollo web y estoy siguiendo un proyecto que está en marcha, hay algunas cosas que se me escapan de mi pequeño conocimiento todavia, desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo quiere manipular el año puedes utilizar un input numérico, en caso que no requieras utilizar librerías como Jquery Ui o DateTimePicker.

Y con JavaScript le puedes decir que el año máximo es 2020 extrayendo el año de la fecha actual. Además le indicas el mínimo que sería el año actual - 6 como lo indicas. Eso permitirá elegir hasta 2014.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var date = new Date();
document.getElementById("fecha").value = date.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("fecha").min = date.getFullYear() - 6;
document.getElementById("fecha").max = date.getFullYear();



var min = date.getFullYear() - 6,
  max = date.getFullYear(),
  select = document.getElementById('selectDate');

for (var i = max; i >= min; i--) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = i;
  opt.innerHTML = i;
  select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<input id="fecha" type="number" min="1900" max="2099" step="1" value="" />
<br>
<label for="cars">Elija una fehca</label>
<select id="selectDate">
</select>
```

En caso de que no quieras utilzar un input numerico puedes crear un select de HTML y rellenarlo con JavaScript para mostrar lo que deseas.

Comment: Mil gracias, me dejaste un claro ejemplo, me funcionó como estaba necesitando, un abrazo!

Comment: Edite la pregunta para ordenar el select. Al final estamos para ayudar. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar, para lo que querés realizar, jquery.
Creas un datepicker en html y le seteas el formato de solo años

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy' })
```

Luego le seteas el rango, deberías cambiar en el ejemplo que pongo debajo la obtención del año actual - el rango que necesites.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({

  yearRange: "2002:2012"
});
```

[Acá](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) podes consultar la documentación que es clara y extensa.

Y te dejó algun que otro ejemplo [acá](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/show-only-month-and-year-in-jquery-ui.html)

Si esto no te sirve, no tenés muchas opciones mas que validar del lado cliente un textBox ingresado por el usuario.